# Which loop is the fastest in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

There are the `for` , `while` and `do-while` in J2ME. Which of them is the fastest ?

Comment: in generated bytecode they are quite similar, i.e. no difference.

Comment: 1) Generally speaking, trying to improve performance by hand optimizing at this level is a waste of time in any language with an optimizing compiler. 2) A typical developer's intuition as to where the real performance bottlenecks are is not very good / accurate.  3) Hand optimizing without first measuring performance (i.e. profiling) is generally a waste of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have some sort of information that is not generally available, these loops are all the same in terms of performance.

Looping overhead is generally not a performance bottleneck.

Comment: To nitpick, loop *overhead* is not a performance bottleneck. Looping itself is usually *the* performance bottleneck (which is why we use big O notation to analyse time complexity), but, as you say, that won't be changed by using a different sort of loop.

Answer (score 7):

The most important thing is to use the simplest and clearest loop for the problem.

I would suggest `for` is notionally longer because it can be used initialise a variable. If instead you initialise a variable before the loop, it will be the same.

If you compare the byte-code for

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

which is

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...);
   0: iconst_0      
   1: istore_1      
   2: iload_1       
   3: bipush        10
   5: if_icmpge     14
   8: iinc          1, 1
  11: goto          2

  14: iconst_0      
  15: istore_1      
  16: iload_1       
  17: bipush        10
  19: if_icmpge     28
  22: iinc          1, 1
  25: goto          16
  28: return
```

You can see the byte code is exactly the same.

do/while is very similar but the difference is that it doesn't check on the first iteration.  If you always want to loop at least once do/while is the correct loop to use, not because it is faster but because it is clearer.